# Espacios en blanco u otro error

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy trabajando con los siguientes datos:

> `Borough  District    latitude    longitude
>   12  Manhattan CB 3  East Village    40.729269   -73.987361
>   13  Manhattan CB 3  Lower East Side 40.715936   -73.986806
>   14  Manhattan CB 3  Two Bridges 40.711288   -73.992233
>   15  Manhattan CB 4  Chelsea 40.746491   -74.001528
>   16  Manhattan CB 4  Clinton 44.727894   -73.668698
>   17  Manhattan CB 4  Hell's Kitchen  40.764423   -73.992392
>   19  Manhattan CB 5  Midtown 40.762268   -73.979544
>   20  Manhattan CB 6  Gramercy Park   40.737925   -73.985932
>   21  Manhattan CB 6  Kips Bay    40.739546   -73.977083
>   22  Manhattan CB 6  Rose Hill   40.743338   -73.984159
>   23  Manhattan CB 6  Murray Hill 40.748157   -73.978750
>   24  Manhattan CB 6  Peter Cooper Village    40.733960   -73.977423
>   25  Manhattan CB 6  Stuyvesant Town 40.731971   -73.978093
>   26  Manhattan CB 6  Sutton Place    41.114852   -72.371285
>   27  Manhattan CB 6  Tudor City  40.748623   -73.971389
>   28  Manhattan CB 6  Turtle Bay  40.753467   -73.968866
>   29  Manhattan CB 6  Waterside Plaza 40.737581   -73.973242
>   30  Manhattan CB 7  Lincoln Square  40.772319   -73.984401
>   31  Manhattan CB 7  Manhattan Valley    40.799776   -73.967772
>   32  Manhattan CB 7  Upper West Side 40.787045   -73.975416
>   33  Manhattan CB 8  Lenox Hill  40.766437   -73.959017
>   34  Manhattan CB 8  Roosevelt Island    40.761418   -73.950228
>   35  Manhattan CB 8  Upper East Side 40.773702   -73.964120
>   36  Manhattan CB 8  Yorkville   40.778007   -73.948202
>   37  Manhattan CB 9  Hamilton Heights    40.824145   -73.950062
>   38  Manhattan CB 9  Manhattanville  40.815778   -73.951554
>   39  Manhattan CB 9  Morningside Heights 40.810000   -73.962500
>   40  Manhattan CB 10 Harlem  40.807879   -73.945415
>   41  Manhattan CB 10 Polo Grounds    41.101948   -72.373218
>   42  Manhattan CB 11 East Harlem 40.794722   -73.942500
>   43  Manhattan CB 11 Randall's Island    40.796768   -73.922082
>   45  Manhattan CB 11 Wards Island    40.787601   -73.925415
>   46  Manhattan CB 12 Inwood  40.869258   -73.920495
>   47  Manhattan CB 12 Washington Heights  40.840198   -73.940221`

El tamaño del DF es de 47 filas, en cada una de ellas hay un distrito su longitud y latitud. Esto me serviría para poder ubicar tiendas en cada distrito de Manhatan para luego hacer una comparación con un distrito similar en Barcelona.

Con el DF hacía la siguiente iteración:

```
for i in range(len (NY)):

# We choose to search by category with a 500m radius.
radius = 500
LIMIT = 100
category_id = '4bf58dd8d48988d102951735' #ID for Accessory stores

latitude = NY['latitude'][i]
longitude = NY['longitude'][i]

# Define the corresponding URL
url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id={}&client_secret={}&ll={},{}&v={}&categoryId={}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, latitude, longitude, VERSION, category_id, radius, LIMIT)

# Send the GET Request
results = requests.get(url).json()

# Get relevant part of JSON and transform it into a pandas dataframe
# assign relevant part of JSON to venues
venues = results['response']['venues']

# tranform venues into a dataframe
dataframe = json_normalize(venues)
dataframe.head()

# keep only columns that include venue name, and anything that is associated with location
filtered_columns = ['name', 'categories'] + [col for col in dataframe.columns if col.startswith('location.')] + ['id']
dataframe_filtered = dataframe.loc[:, filtered_columns]

# function that extracts the category of the venue
def get_category_type(row):
    try:
        categories_list = row['categories']
    except:
        categories_list = row['venue.categories']

    if len(categories_list) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return categories_list[0]['name']

# filter the category for each row
dataframe_filtered['categories'] = dataframe_filtered.apply(get_category_type, axis=1)

# clean column names by keeping only last term
dataframe_filtered.columns = [column.split('.')[-1] for column in dataframe_filtered.columns]

print(str(i) + ') The number of shops in ' +NY['District'][i] + ' is ' +str(dataframe_filtered.shape[0]) + '\n')
N_shop.append(dataframe_filtered.shape[0])
```

Ahora la iteración va funcionando pero cuando llega a la fila nº 16 salta este error:

> 13) The number of shops in LowerEastSide is 12
>
> ```
> 14) The number of shops in TwoBridges is 1
>
> 15) The number of shops in Chelsea is 10
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)    <ipython-input-72-a1327a0e7acb> in <module>
>  25     # keep only columns that include venue name, and anything that is 
> associated with location
>  26     filtered_columns = ['name', 'categories'] + [col for col in 
> dataframe.columns if col.startswith('location.')] + ['id']
> ---> 27     dataframe_filtered = dataframe.loc[:, filtered_columns]
>  28 
>  29     # function that extracts the category of the venue
>
> /opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py
>
> in __getitem__(self, key)    1492             except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):    1493                 pass
> ```
>
> -> 1494             return self._getitem_tuple(key)    1495         else:    1496             # we by definition only have the 0th axis
>
> /opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py
>   in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
>       886                 continue
>       887 
>   --> 888             retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
>       889 
>       890         return retval
>
> /opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py
>   in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)    1900                     raise
>   ValueError('Cannot index with multidimensional key')    1901 
>   -> 1902                 return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)    1903     1904             # nested tuple slicing
>
> /opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py
>   in _getitem_iterable(self, key, axis)    1203             # A
>   collection of keys    1204             keyarr, indexer =
>   self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis,
>   -> 1205                                                          raise_missing=False)    1206             return
>   self.obj._reindex_with_indexers({axis: [keyarr, indexer]},    1207
>   copy=True, allow_dups=True)
>
> /opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py
>   in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)    1159
>   self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer,    1160
>   o._get_axis_number(axis),
>   -> 1161                                     raise_missing=raise_missing)    1162         return keyarr, indexer
>   1163
>
> /opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py
>   in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
>   1244                 raise KeyError(    1245
>   u"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis}]".format(
>   -> 1246                         key=key, axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))    1247     1248             # We
>   (temporarily) allow for some missing keys with .loc, except in
>
> KeyError: "None of [Index(['name', 'categories', 'id'],
>   dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Por lo que entiendo (en mi poca experiencia) hay un error a partir de la fila 16 que hace que la iteración se interrumpa, pero no he podido darme cuenta que y como solucionarlo.

Comment: Puedes poner el rango de filas donde te falla? SI te falla en la 16, muestra de 13-a 19 o 15 a 20, pero no de 1 a 10 xD, Edita y cambia el ejemplo por el rango de filas donde falla e intentamos ver que sucede ;)

Comment: Gracias Sergio por tu respuesta, he editado el post.

Comment: Te has fijado que justo la linea 17 tiene una coma `'`?
Podrías realizar una "prueba definitiva" para comprobar, es quitar o saltar esa linea, algo como `"if line == 17" continue` y ver si vuelve a fallar en la 42, porque en la 43 vuelves a tener una coma. Si esto es así, es posible que te haga falta algún tipo de escapado de código para incluir esos caracteres especiales.

Comment: A demás, he revisado tu edición anterior donde pusiste las primeras lineas y efectivamente como sospechaba, no tienes `'`, la tilde como caracter especial. Ahora que sabes que puede ser, igual puede solucionarlo. Si no te aclaras como procesar esa tilde `'`, comenta para confirmar el problema e intento solucionarlo ;)

Comment: Hola Sergio, gracias por la respuesta. He probado lo que me dices de quitar la fila 17 pero no ha dado resultado. Pero a raíz de tu recomendación he modificado la iteración y la he ido probando por tramos, es decir. He cambiado el "for i in range(len (NY))" por "for i in np.arange(0,NY.shape[0])"  y he ido probando a lo largo de todas las filas y me he dado cuenta que fallan en varios sitios. No entiendo el porque, pero el error es el mismo. He llegado a deducir que esta relacionado con el nombre del distrito que al parecer el loop no lo encuentra.

Comment: Hay alguna función para poder ejecutar la iteración y si una fila da error, la salteé y siga con la siguiente?